# Awk command not working in csh

Tags: scripting, awk, csh

Please let me know what is wrong with below code:

```
#!/bin/csh
set str = "peanut"
set sr = "an"
awk 'BEGIN { print index($str,$sr) }'
```

The error is awk: Field  is not correct.  The source line number is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$variable` strings are not interpreted by Csh within the 'single quotes'.

Perhaps the simplest fix is to use (GNU) Awk variables as command-line parameters:

```
#!/bin/csh
set str = "peanut"
set sr = "an"
awk -vstr=$str -vsr=$sr 'BEGIN { print index(str, sr)}'
```

Comment: and of course, do not use csh for scripting. Google "csh why not".